# Changing font colors of rows and columns with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am looking for a way to change the font colors of the row and column contents of a table with the assigned checkbox at the top and on the left side of the table. so when a checkbox is clicked either a corresponding row or column contents change font color. I don't need multiple colors. I just need to change font color to an assigned color only. Multiple row checkbox and column checkboxes may be clicked together, this shouldn't cause a complication. Thank you for your help!

Here is a jsfiddle also: https://jsfiddle.net/u6xzfnq7/

```css
.tb {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
  

 <table class="tb">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check4" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check5" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check6" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check7" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check8" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check10" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check11" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check12" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check13" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check14" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check15" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check16" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check17" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check18" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check19" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check20" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check21" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check22" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="color-switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="check23" /> Switch</label>
            </td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: you have non-unique ids, the id "check" is used for every checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. I changed the "id"s.

Comment: So add a class to the row when checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
//Add listener on checbox inside the table with class .tb
$('.tb input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  //Remove all selected
  $('.tb td').removeClass('selected');

  //Add class on rows
  //Select all checked checkbox on the first column
  //Select the parent td and select its siblings
  //Add Class
  $('.tb tr>td:first-child').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('selected').siblings().addClass('selected');
  })

  //Add class on columns
  //Select all checkboxes on the first row.
  //Loop and check if checked.
  //If checked, add class on the column
  $('.tb tr:first-child').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
      $('.tb tr>td:nth-child(' + (i + 2) + ')').addClass('selected');
  })
})
```

```css
.tb {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
    <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
                <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eddie. This is perfect. What I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Just to tell you, I've played with your code and added a new answer. I'm telling you because you'll maybe want to consider some of the methods I used. :) Please don't take it as an attack!…

Comment: @TakitIsy Thank you for informing me, I considered your code and I think I'll stick with mine :) You added the class on `<tr>` and on `<td>` which makes it inconsistent. Not really my thing. Thank you for informing me though :)

Comment: @Eddie Sure, but I found it was funny to be able to stylize intersections. Anyway, it will be easy to stylize all the tds instead of the tr. I found that your instruction `$(this).parent().parent().addClass('selected').siblings().addClass('selected');` was way too complicated. That was mainly because of it than I wanted to enhance your answer! ;)

Comment: Really? Is it funny? Is it complicated? I guess we don't see eye to eye with those things :) And this is not the first time you did this. You are just enhancing people's answer. I mean there is nothing wrong with that but if you do that alot, come on now :)

Comment: I must repeat myself but… That wasn't an attack. I found that `$(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');` was way easier to write and understand than `$(this).parent().parent().addClass('selected').siblings().addClass('selected');`. But maybe I'm just crazy. Anyway, in the topic you linked, you could admit that there was actually too much opening and closing php tags! I thought it was common sense to explain how it was possible to avoid that. Now I'm beginning to feel like you're only saying "I'll stick with mine [code]" because you took my comment badly.

Comment: As I have said also, adding class to `<tr>` and on `<td>` are inconsistent for me. And not my thing. And my answer on my post is based on OPs original post and not the issue :)

Comment: Ohh no, i did not feel bad. Ill stick with my code because it is **consistent** with adding the color class on `<td>`. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will do it in the following way:

```js
var color = "red";
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
  var idNum = $(this).attr('id').replace('check','');
  if(idNum > 7){
    if(isChecked)
      $(this).closest('td').siblings().css('color', color);
    else
      $(this).closest('td').siblings().css('color', '');
  }
  else if(idNum < 23){
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings().each(function(i, tr){
      if(isChecked)
        $(this).find('td:eq("'+idNum+'")').css('color', color);
      else
        $(this).find('td:eq("'+idNum+'")').css('color', '');
    }); 
  }
})
```

```css
.tb {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.nochange,
tr {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check1" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check4" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check5" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check6" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check7" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check8" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check10" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check11" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check12" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check13" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check14" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check15" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check16" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check17" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check18" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check19" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check20" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check21" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check22" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <label class="color-switch">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check23" /> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mamun.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted Eddie's answer, but here it is anyway.
Trying to enhance his answer, here is a snippet showing what I'll do.
Please take time to consider the methods used in the javascript, that's the only thing I've changed from Eddie's code. I've added comments to make it clearer.

Plus, I added something funny in the CSS!

```js
// Listen to checkboxes change on table
$('.tb input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  // Remove the class on all trs and tds
  $('.tb tr, .tb td').removeClass('selected');

  // Add the class only to checked trs (rows)
  // Note that there is no need to use the .find() method
  // You can just move the whole selection string in the $() query
  $('.tb tr>td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    // closest() is a really nice method, consider it! Way clearer than .parent().parent()…
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
  })

  // Add the class only to checked tds (columns)
  var tds = $('.tb tr:first-child td');
  $('.tb tr:first-child input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest('td').each(function() {
    // The each only contains selected tds, not all of them
    // Get index for each of the selecteds (+1 because index starts at 0) and style them!
    $('.tb tr>td:nth-child(' + (tds.index($(this)) + 1) + ')').addClass('selected');
  })
})
```

```css
.tb {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tb td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}


/* The funny thing is that we could stylize intersections */

.selected .selected {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tb">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
    <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="color-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"/> Switch</label>
      </td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
      <td>Number</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

More about `.closest()`: https://api.jquery.com/closest/
More about `.index()`: https://api.jquery.com/index/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Takit Isy.

Comment: @Max I'm glad if you found it useful!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this was what you were after.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnzurbt5/).

```
<table class="tb">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <label class="color-switch">
            <input data-col="0" type="checkbox" /> Switch</label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <label class="color-switch">
            <input data-col="1" type="checkbox" /> Switch</label>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <label class="color-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" data-row="0" /> Switch</label>
         </td>
         <td data-row="0" data-col="0">Text</td>
         <td data-row="0" data-col="1">Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <label class="color-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" data-row="1" /> Switch</label>
         </td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="0">Text</td>
         <td data-row="1" data-col="1">Text</td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
   .tb {
       font-size: 12px;
       border: 1px solid #CCC;
       font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   .tb td {
       padding: 4px;
       margin: 3px;
       border: 1px solid #CCC;
   }
   .nochange,
   tr {
    background-color: white;
   }

   td.row-checked.col-checked{
    color: red;
   }
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $inputCheckboxRow = $('input[type="checkbox"][data-row]');
    var $inputCheckboxCol =  $('input[type="checkbox"][data-col]');

    $inputCheckboxRow.on('change', onInputCheckBoxRowChange );
    $inputCheckboxCol.on('change', onInputCheckboxColChange );

    function onInputCheckBoxRowChange(){
        let row = $(this).data('row');
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('td[data-row='+ row +']').addClass('row-checked')
        }else{
            $('td[data-row='+ row +']').removeClass('row-checked')
        }
    }

    function onInputCheckboxColChange(){
        let col = $(this).data('col');
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('td[data-col='+ col +']').addClass('col-checked')
        }else{
            $('td[data-col='+ col +']').removeClass('col-checked')
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikksan. I tried it on fiddle. but it seems it's not exactly what i wanted. I got answer now. thanks for your time and help.